# Java Ant build with external libraries

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I have following target in mz ant script to build my java application

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile" description="generate jar">
    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/jar/final.jar" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="my.package.Main" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

What I need is to somehow include log4j into the jar, as it throws a NoClassDefFoundError when running with

```
java -jar final.jar
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could solve my problem with [zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)

```
    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/jar/final.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}/classes" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="my.pacakge.Main" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
```

Comment: It's funny. I've tried every one of the many solutions to this that I've found around the Internet and SO, and this is the only one that worked for me. I don't know why is the process of including an external JAR such a pain. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

try adding includes parametersettings to it, like

```
includes="<path-to-log4j-folder>/*.jar"
```

Detailed syntax is [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Comment: including a jar into a jar did not seem to work. the included jar does not seem to bein the classpath.

Comment: Try adding it as a child of jar task, like..   <jar jarfile=.. 
      <classpath>
       <pathelement path="<path-to-log4j-folder>"/>
      </classpath>